# Measuring CPU frequency on windows/arm platform

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, arm, system, cpu-architecture

I have seen many posts regarding CPU frequency but these have (x86) assembly code with RDTSC instruction. Can anyone let me know of a more generic or ARM architecture specific method to measure CPU frequency on windows phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

In linux we have the below sysfs entries, which can tell you about the cpu current frequency :

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq

Comment: But I need it for windows phone.